# ¿Cómo configurar auto-completado de Materialize para filtrar por los primeros caracteres que coincidan?

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Mi intención es configurar el filtro de `materialize` para que al digitar me traiga únicamente los datos que contengan los caracteres digitados al inicio de la cadena de texto.

Como se ve en la imagen *(Es lo que no quiero que pase)*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$(function() {
  $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: {
      "Analista Senior": null,
      "Analista Junior": null,
      "Auxiliar": null,
      "Administrador": null,
      "Coordinador": null
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Autocomplete MaterializeCSS</title>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s13">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
          <input type="text" id="autocomplete" class="autocomplete">
          <label for="autocomplete">Autocomplete</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola @And ¿te refieres a que lo ingresado solo se compare y coincidia con el principio de la palabra?

Comment: @Jorius Exactamente eso es mi intención.

Comment: ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta y poner el ejemplo, fuente o la documentación de `.autocomplete()` ?

Comment: Al parecer Materialize no posee esa configuración, una opción sería agregar esa excepción en el código de la librería.

Comment: La verdad es que solo encuentro documentación para esa función '*`.autocomplete()`*' en la librería de [JqueryUI](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) ¿es esa la que estás usando?

Comment: @Jorius efectivamente JQueryUI posee esa característica y me fue sencillo modificar el código para que realizara dicha función pero ahora requiero que materialize haga lo mismo

Comment: @And simplemente añadiste el `css` de materialize, en si, quien realiza esa función sigue siendo el JqueryUI, por lo que he visto en la documentación no tienen algo oficial para lo que tu quieres, tendrías que realizar algún 'hack' jaja

Comment: @Jorius no está usando el autocomplete de jQuery UI. MaterializeCSS tiene su propio autocomplete. Acabo de comprobarlo: http://materializecss.com/forms.html#autocomplete aparentemente lo añadieron en la versión 0.98. Corrigo, fue en la 0.97.7 https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/releases/tag/v0.97.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Respuesta corta**: no se puede. El plugin autocomplete de materialize sólo acepta como parámetros de configuración un objeto del tipo:

```
var conf = {
  data:{...},
  limit:xx,
  onAutocomplete: function() {}
  minLength: xx
}
```

Y como verás no hay ahí opción para establecer que el match se restrinja al inicio del objeto de resultados

**Respuesta larga**: si estás pensando en modificar el plugin que viene en materialize, sí se puede. Lamentablemente no es tan trivial como sobreescribir un método de `$.fn.autocomplete` porque el match se comprueba en un closure declarado dentro del constructor, y no en un método como en el caso de jQuery-UI.

Dicho esto, en el closure declarado en [forms.js#L345](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/js/forms.js#L345), específicamente en donde comprueba la existencia de la cadena entre tu objeto data:

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) &&
    key.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 &&
    key.toLowerCase() !== val) {

    ...
}
```

Tendrías que poner

```
if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) &&
    key.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) === 0 &&
    key.toLowerCase() !== val) {

    ...
}
```

Para que esto funcione, me parece que la única manera sería cargar tu propio `$.fn.autocomplete` después de haber cargado materialize. Y si vas a cargar tu propia versión del plugin, entonces sería más o menos lo mismo que cargar otra librería de autocompletado como select2, selectize o chosen.

Comment: Logre hacer que funcionara el Materialize con el JQueryUI

Answer (score 0):

"Logre hacer que funcionara el Materialize con el JQueryUI" – user25693 el 13 mar. 17 a las 16:10

Que tal amigo, como lograste que funcionara? estoy pasando por el mismo problema, inclui la funcion de autocompletar de materialize en mi formulario y quiero que se muestren solo las sugerencias que comienzan por el mismo caracter y no todos los que lo incluyan, agradezco tu respuesta